# Cannot read file from config in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, config

I am working on spring boot app and in my config file I have couple o file and I want to read them. so I have tried below stuffs.

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=local -Dserver.port=8080 -Dajp.port=0 -Dspring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:OraDoc -Dspring.datasource.username=system -Dspring.datasource.password=MyPasswd123 -Dspring.config.additional-location=file:/Users/bharatsuthar/HGW/codebaseDevelopmentRepo1/data-generation-tool/rdk-factory-data-config/ -Dlogging.config=file:/Users/bharatsuthar/HGW/codebaseDevelopmentRepo1/data-generation-tool/rdk-factory-data-config/logback-spring.xml
```

I am able to read all files since spring is supporting this by using **-Dspring.config.additional-location** but I am not sure how to read **test.pem** file in my java code as a String only.

below is my test.pem file location under **rdk-factory-data-config directory**

[location of test pem file]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T0Y8.png)

I tried with **-Dspring.config.additional-location** here i am able to read file like application.yml and application-dev.yml but how can I read the **test.pem** file to String in my java code.
I want to read pem file into String so that I can read the data in my spring boot app.

content of pem file :

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I have tried this -

```
String s = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("test.pem")));           System.out.println("s=" + s);
```

-> it gives me no such file exception -->

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: test.pem
```

---> I don't want to give full absolute path since my requirement is to read from directory which is in the root of my spring boot folder

thank you so much

Comment: Did you try `FileInputStream`/`FileReader`?

Comment: I have tried this - ```String s = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("test.pem")));
   System.out.println("s=" + s);```.   -> it gives me no such file exception --> Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: test.pem---> I don't want to give full absolute path since my requirement is to read from directory which is in the root of my spring boot folder

Comment: Did you try:
    FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource("test.pem");
    IOUtils.toString(resource.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

see also https://www.baeldung.com/spring-properties-file-outside-jar

Comment: What bothers me is that OP is able to use IOC container like Spring with a deep understanding of how its external configuration works (profiles, additional-location etc) and yet does not know the very bacis like reading files. How come?

Comment: Have you tried using absolute path to the file? Most probably relative path `test.pem` is not pointing to the place you think it does.

Comment: Where is the `test.pem` file located? Where is the application (JAR) located? What location are you running the `java` command from?

Comment: rather than this , how can I pass the entire pem file in some arguement let's say ```-DmyPem=/location/test.pem``` and then read this pem file in my code. how can I achieve this ? any idea and then I ll run my jar file like this ```java -jar myjar.jar -DmyPem=/location/test.pem```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, **-Dspring.config.additional-location** reads any **property** file or equivalent of it. *.pem files are not equivalent of property files so they should be ignored. [Read Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

What you should do instead, put a property in your property file specifying your .pem file location and later, use that property to read the contents of your .pem file in whatever format seems fit to you.

Comment: rather than this , how can I pass the entire pem file in some arguement let's say ```-DmyPem=/location/test.pem``` and then read this pem file in my code. how can I achieve this ? any idea and then I ll run my jar file like this ```java -jar myjar.jar -DmyPem=/location/test.pem```

Comment: you can pass any key=value pair using `-D` switch and then, use `@Value` annotation to inject the value directly in your bean.

Comment: You should read about this in the documentation I provided link for. Take @antoniossss comment seriously.